# Not calling TypeConverter

Tags: android

Not calling TypeConverter

I am tying, calling innerRateToJson but never fromJsonToInnerRates

```
class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun innerRateToJson(innerRate : HashMap<String, Double>): String? {
        val type = object : TypeToken<HashMap<String, Double>>() {}.type
        return Gson().toJson(innerRate, type)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromJsonToInnerRates(innerRatesString : String): HashMap<String, Double>? {
        val type = object : TypeToken<HashMap<String, Double>>() {}.type
        return Gson().fromJson<HashMap<String, Double>>(innerRatesString, type)
    }
}
```

and my data class

```
data class Rates (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "base")
    @SerializedName("base")
    val base: String,

    @ColumnInfo (name = "date")
    @SerializedName ("date")
    val date: String,

    @ColumnInfo (name = "rates")
    @SerializedName ("rates")
    @TypeConverters(Converters::class)
   val rates: HashMap<String, Double> = HashMap()
) : Parcelable
```

Don't know what to do

Comment: What type of error are you getting?

Comment: No errors, just not writing to db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of your variable modifier.
setting a variable as `val` it will make it read-only, so you can't access it.
just switch it to `var`.

```
@ColumnInfo (name = "rates")
@SerializedName ("rates")
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
var rates: HashMap<String, Double> = HashMap()
```

you can check the difference between `var` and `val` [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters).
You should also define your converter on AppDatabase class.

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Rates::class), version = 1)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class AppDatabse : RoomDatabase()
```

try to use `@JvmStatic` below `@TypeConverter`, so it looks like this

```
@TypeConverter
@JvmStatic
    fun innerRateToJson(innerRate : HashMap<String, Double>): String? {
        val type = object : TypeToken<HashMap<String, Double>>() {}.type
        return Gson().toJson(innerRate, type)
    }
```

Comment: made var - no changes